# What is appropriate icons to report something bad?

Tags: icons

Another UI question:

User should be able to report unusual activities to the system admin

what icon can i use for that

youtube uses "Flag" but I don't see any meaning there.

[image]

Comment: It's like you are lifting(hoisting) flag as pointing a fact.

Comment: Essentially a flag is used to identify something. Take for example a country's flag. Similarly, when you flag a video, you get different options as to what you want to flag it as for e.g. Nudity. Now, this flag can be reviewed by Youtube to remove/unlist the video for Nudity.

Answer (score 1):

I think flag is appropriate though. Like Swapnil Borkar said in his comment: it's used to identify an object as something (error, unappropriate content, etc.)

But then again, it also depends on the context you're asking. For bugs, usually the icon is a [bug](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bug/), for errors it could be an [exclamation mark](http://fontawesome.io/icon/exclamation-triangle/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this icon: URL:[click here for Icon](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhvEWaI_EJ5s5YW_Nvnmj0b40rpJPNPFN_geGF-6NyGyUMUPRp)

report is regarding your work like what is done or whit is going on and what is result till data.

Comment: i wish you could read my question.